# Can I see how many times I reinstalled an app, after I delete it?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore

After I deleted an application from my iPhone, is there a way to find how many times that application was deleted and reinstalled on my account?

Answer (score 1):

Shot answer is no. Long answer is why?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method to see that. Unless you can go on your router and locate the logs from about when you got it from. That would be a very hard process, nearly impossible.

Comment: Would require the router to keep a log of all URLs visited (which usually isn't done). Also apps reinstalled via iTunes on Mac/PC will be installed without internet traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In your iTunes account you can see Purchase History, including free apps. It won't show when it was deleted, and may not show re-installed apps.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088

[image]